# Dúvida busca binária c++

Tags: c++

https://www.codepit.io/#/problems/5369c33df6fa9de49e5c7d0e/view?index=1

Consegui resolver essa questão da seguinte forma:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int contar_pares(int y, int x[], int tam){
    int cont = 0;
    for(int i = tam; i > 0; i--){
        for(int j = tam - 1; j >= 0; j--){
            if(x[i-1] - x[j] == y){
               cont++;
            }
        }
    }
    return cont;
}

int main(){
    int n, k;
    cin >> n >> k;
    int tamanho = n;
    int vetor[tamanho];
    for(int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++){
        cin >> vetor[i];
    }
    sort(vetor, vetor + tamanho);
    cout << contar_pares(k, vetor, tamanho) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Mas quando submeto da tempo limite excedido... Alguns colegas meus conseguiram resolver com busca binária, mas a minha dúvida é: como conto quantas vezes o k vai ser encontrado dentro de uma busca binária?

Comment: Melhor que uma busca binária é utilizar um `set` como se fosse uma hashtable, que até aproveita os recursos que o c++ lhe dá, e joga com as restrições do problema que indicam que os números são distintos e não se repetem. Para além disso aumenta-lhe a complexidade de tempo de O(nlogn) para O(n), sendo que no exemplo do seu código é O(n^2). [Exemplo de solução utilizando `set`](https://ideone.com/Q5XUom).

Answer (score 2):

Para utilizar busca binária, primeiro precisarás ordenar o array de elementos. Isso baixará a complexidade de O(n<sup>2</sup>) - tua solução -  para O(n log n) (complexidade do ordenamento, utilizando [quicksort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/), por exemplo). Para contar o número de ocorrências da diferença, faze uma busca binária por `n+k` no array ordenado (onde n é o nº que estás contando as diferenças no momento e k a diferença). Se encontrares o elemento, incrementa o contador.

Todavia, como @Isac falou no comentário, essa ainda não é a melhor opção - a [solução proposta por ele](https://ideone.com/Q5XUom) resolve o problema de forma mais rápida, sem precisar ordenar os elementos, reduzindo a complexidade de velocidade para O(n).